# how to redirect to another page using php after hosting my website

Tags: javascript, php

hello guys please help

How to redirect a page using php?
i am using this one

```
header('location:quizsection.php?success=success');
```

It is working on localhost
but after hosting my website it is not working

**it is working on perfectly when i using with local server it is not working after i am hosting this on godaddy**

and

**path is also pefect**

Comment: Where is this quizsection.php file located and from which file are you calling the redirection?

Comment: Can you enable error reporting and check if there are any errors.

Comment: If the path is "pefect", it is very possible that you typo'd a directory or file name. Look at the error logs to see what the true problem is.

Comment: if you host it in a free host like `000webhost` it disables redirection from `php` so you can make your redirect from `js` by using `window.location = "url to redirect"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
header('location: /quizsection.php?success=success');
```

Comment: Can you add explanation for your answer? How you thought the path is incorrect?

Comment: Because he didin't explaine about any error header or anything else, so probably is path error.

Comment: Then you should have asked the OP about that. Anyways I got my answer.

Comment: it is working on perfectly when i using with local server it is not working after i am hosting this on godaddy

Comment: So enable error reporting for find which is the real problem we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When I redirect, I go overboard to ensure redirection takes place. I do this:

```
$url = "quizsection.php?success=success";
header('Location: '.$url);
die("<html>
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; $url'>
  <body onload=\"location.replace('$url');\">
  <a href='$url'>$url</a>
  </body></html>");
```

Notice that I have a space after "Location:", which you do not have. If the header is ignored, I send HTML. It includes a meta tag to redirect. If that is ignored, the page uses Javascript to redirect. If that is ignored, the user sees the URL and nothing else. The user can click on it to get to the URL.

I actually have this in a function called redirect, so I just use:

```
redirect("quizsection.php?success=success");
```

If this doesn't work, it isn't a redirection problem. You need to check your directories and files. Something is not where you think it is or is not named what you think it is. I've personally spent days working on problems that were caused by a misnamed directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

When you print something in PHP, it changes that into HTML and that's what the file shows. So when you think about it you have to do the following:

```
print("<script type=text/javascript>location.href = \"quizsection.php?success=success\";</script>");
```

Tell me if this works! If you want to delay the redirect do this:

```
print("<script type=text/javascript>function redirect() {location.href = \"quizsection.php?success=success\"} setTimeout(redirect, amountOfMilliseconds)</script>");
```

FYI, there are 1000 milliseconds in a second. Let me know if this works!